# How does Gulp know when an asynchronous dependent task is complete (specifically, 'gulp-connect')?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, gulp

Learning Gulp, I see this simple example that runs a second task after a first is complete:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');

// First task
gulp.task('connect', function() {
    // No callback is provided to Gulp to indicate when the server is connected!
    connect.server();
});

// Second task runs after the first task 'completes'
gulp.task('open', ['connect'], function() {

    // v v v
    // Question: since no callback is provided to indicate when 'connect' completes,
    // how does Gulp know when to run this task?

    // Some task here...
});
```

My question is straightforward.

I think that the `connect.server()` task must be asynchronous, so that somewhere in its implementation is:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    // Presumably, before the first request can be received,
    // there must be an asynchronous delay while the server initializes

    /// ...handle HTTP requests here...
});
```

I assume that there is an asynchronous delay before the first request can be received in that first task - and only when requests are ready to be received should the first task be considered 'complete', so that Gulp can run the second task.

Given this, how does Gulp know that the server is fully connected and receiving requests so that it knows to run the second task?

I do not see a callback provided to Gulp that can be used by Gulp as a trigger to indicate that the next task is ready to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I don't believe you could be 100% sure for 2 reasons.

The first is that you're not passing a callback to your `connect` task.
The second is that you're not using a callback in your `server.listen()`

Gulp allows tasks to pass a callback in to the [task function](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support) for explicit signaling that a task is complete.

You could do something like this

#### gulpfile

```
gulp.task('connect', function(done) {
    connect.server(function() {
        return done();
    });
});
```

#### server

```
module.exports = function(callback) {
    let server = http.createServer();
    let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    // all of your routes and server logic

    server.listen(port, function() {
        console.log('listening on ' + port);            
        if (callback)
            return callback;            
    });
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I do not have access to the code that is internal to `gulp-connect`, where the `http.createServer` and `server.listen` is called.  Perhaps it is impossible to use the `gulp-connect` plugin in a way that guarantees the server will have initialized when the `connect` task is a dependent task?  Note: I have seen a number of references to `gulp-connect` as a highly used and useful gulp plugin, which is why I am trying to understand these details.

Comment: In that case you could use `setTimeout()` inside your `'connect'` task, its a bit inaccurate but you could cause the gulp task to wait 1-2 seconds which would be more than enough time. `setTimeout(2000, function() { return done() });` would be enough.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines - but really, if it comes down to setting a timeout, really I think the answer to the question is simply **'nope - it doesn't'**.  Just good to know the state of the `Gulp` ecosystem, insofar as `gulp-connect` represents this.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Yeah, I'd say if you don't have access to `server.listen()` then the answer is no, there is no precise way to know the server is listening without polling a route.